# Code working in django terminal but not in django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

This code below works in the terminal but when I try it in Django templates I get an error (see error below).

However this code works just fine in my django terminal

```
>>> for item in order_items:
...     if item.reviewed_items.exists():
...             item.reviewed_items.values_list('ratings', flat=True)[0]
... 
'8'
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong

```
    {%  for item in order_items  %} 

           {% if item.reviewed_items.exists %}
              <span>Your Review</span><br/>                  
              <b>{{ item.reviewed_items.values_list('ratings', flat=True) }}/10</b>
           {% else %}
               <a href="{% url 'accounts:review' username=item.made_by pk=item.pk %}">
                  <button class="text-success">Leave Review</button>
               </a>
          {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /order/history/

    Could not parse the remainder: '('ratings', flat=True)' from 'item.reviewed_items.values_list('ratings', flat=True)'
```

Comment: The documentation is explicit that [you can't call functions with arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls) in Django templates.

Comment: You can not perform function calls (well at least not using Python syntax) in Django templates. THis has been done *deliberately* such that one would *not* write business logic in the templates (like you do :). The idea is that you write this logic in the *view*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  ok thanks I will try to maybe add a `variabe = item.reviewed_items.values_list('ratings', flat=True) `  in the view and then call the variable in the template will that be a right approach

Comment: Well a problem here is that you iterate over `item`s, so you can not calculate this for *an* `item` in the view, you need to construct some sort of list of 2-tuples, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you maybe add that as a answer with a example code

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You _can_ perform function calls (e.g. `mymodel.child_set.all`), just can't pass arguments.